# Laravel Route Api result

Tags: laravel

I would like to return only a few attributs on my Json result from this route API :

```
Route::get('clubs', function () {

 $clubs = App\Clubs::all(); 

 return $clubs;    

});
```

For exemple i would like to get only the name and the city in my response but i get also the full object with 2 more attributs.

What i'm doing wrong ? thanks a lot in advance

```
  Route::get('clubs', function () {

     $clubs = App\Clubs::all(); 

     foreach($clubs as $club){

      $club['name'] = $club->name; 
      $club['city'] = $club->city; 

     }

     return $clubs; 

});
```

Comment: Either you could add a `select` to your collection or you could make use of [Eloquent: API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest way to customize responses and nested resources is using [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources). From the docs:

> When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits
>   between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually
>   returned to your application's users. Laravel's resource classes allow
>   you to expressively and easily transform your models and model
>   collections into JSON.

## Generating API Resources

```php
php artisan make:resource ClubResource
```

Then, modify the **resource class** to your needs:

**App\Http\Resources\ClubResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ClubResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'city' => $this->city,
        ];
    }
}
```

## Using API Resources

Then in your controller you do this:

**App\Http\ClubController.php**

```php
use App\Http\Resources\ClubResource;
use App\Clubs;

class ClubController extends Controller
{

// some of your code

    function index() {

         $clubs = Clubs::all(); // I strongly recommend you to paginate results.

         // This way to return a collection    
         return ClubResource::collection($clubs);

    });


    // for a route like: /clubs/{clubId}

    function show(Request $request) {

         $clubs = Clubs::find($request->clubId);

         // This way to return a single resource
         return new ClubResource($clubs);

    });

// the rest of your code

}
```

## Nesting child resources (from relationships)

As you can see, you can create API Resources for any model, so of course you can create a resource class of the child model and then can be used to format this kind of collection. You can even use it inside some parent resource class like this as the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships) says:

**App\Http\Resources\ClubResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class ClubResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'city' => $this->city,

            // I'm asuming here that a Club has many members

            // You can do this to load the childs only when you specify it:
            'members' => MemberResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('members')),

            // Or like this to always return the child resources
            'members' => MemberResource::collection($this->members),

        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the preferred method to implement together with maintaining a modular structure.

Comment: @VaishnavMhetre exactly. This also allows you to use different resources to return the same data  for different cases or to modify  the current returned data without touching other clases (like controllers or repositories). Is a good way to decouple the code and centralize the maintainace.

Comment: Yes. That's true. Actually Laravel is awesome if it's used in damn crazy modular way. It really helps building system that way.

Comment: @HCK and Vasishnav Mhetre, im out of resource to learn module way in laravel, where can i learn any links please

Comment: @arunkumar check my answer, there you have a couple of links. This video  (of J. A. Curtis/DevMarketer who is good teaching Laravel stuff) can also help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gyr5ZMNaPbc. I strongly recommend you to navigate in the Laravel documentation and also see Laracasts series.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
$clubs = App\Clubs::select('name','city')->get();
```

Comment: Beat me to it xD

Comment: And how i can display a value from a another object who is in relation with club ?

Comment: @MathieuMourareau check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('clubs', function () {

    return App\Clubs::select('name', 'city')->get(); 

});
```