# Laravel Eloquent get all in single key value pair

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables `posts` and `post_metas` with the schema as below:

```
POSTS
+------------+------------------+
| Field      | Type             |
+------------+------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned |
| title      | varchar(255)     |
| content    | longtext         |


POST_METAS
+------------+------------------+
| Field      | Type             |
+------------+------------------+
| id         | int(10) unsigned |
| post_id    | int(10) unsigned |
| key        | varchar(255)     |
| value      | longtext         |
```

using a simple one to many relationship, i get this output

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dibbert LLC",
    "content": null,
    "post_metas": [
      {
        "key": "code",
        "value": "YSRSLBZ7"
      },
      {
        "key": "agent_id",
        "value": "32"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am wondering if it is possible to have the post metas as an object not an array, like this instead:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Dibbert LLC",
    "content": null,
    "post_metas": {
        "code": "YSRSLBZ7",
        "agent_id": "32"
      }
  }
]
```

Comment: How are you querying your `post` to get the `post_meta`? Laravel indeed return a collection of objects that should look like your desired output.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't change how Eloquent returns relationship collections, nor should you want to, but you can certainly manipulate the collection in your response:

```
$model->post_metas->pluck('value', 'key');
```

Read up on all the available [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods).

Answer (score 1):

Laravel by default return an instance of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-collections) class. This is also applied when querying relationship elements.

Now, if you want to customize the fields to be returned (hide, transform or add something, for example), you could use [API Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-resources). This will let you easily transform your responses.

Check [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48890307/7117697) to help you with API Resources.

---

## Update

To implement API Resources to your needs we'll need to:

1. Define the PostResource and PostMetaResource classes.
2. Customize them
3. Use them in the controller to return the desired data to the view/API

### Defining API Resources classes

```php
php artisan make:resource PostMetaResource
php artisan make:resource PostResource
```

### Customization

**App/Http/Resources/PostMetaResource.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\Resource;

class PostMetaResource extends Resource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'key' => $this->key,
            'value' => $this->value,
        ];
    }
}
```

**App/Http/Resources/PostResource.php**

```php
class PostResource extends Resource
{

    use PostMetaResource;

    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            // the rest of your fields..

            // here is where we load the relationship resource:
            'post_metas' => PostMetaResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('post_metas')),
        ];
    }
}
```

### Applying them

```php
use App\Http\Resources\PostResource;

//

public function index(Request $request)
{
    $posts = Post::with('post_metas')->get();

    return PostResource::collection($posts);
}
```

Comment: this answer have everything but the answer ;)
this is currently what i am doing, i am more interested in the last part you referred

Comment: haha, I posted this because the way you output is  right now looks a little bit off to me. I've updated my answer adding a link to an answer I made in the past regarding that subject (API Resources).

Comment: i have to toArray method in the model returning only key and value fields, also i omitted the id and post_ids to keep the question as brief as possible

Comment: can you update your answer to include the Resource method which will give me the output I mentioned in the question?

Comment: @SalalAslam done. I encourage you to read the documentation regarding this subject. Is way more clearer than my response. Have a good day.